# remove pixels between DIVs without deleting whitespace

Tags: html, css

```
.littlebox { margin:2px; padding:5px; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #ccc; display:inline-block; }
.divrow { width:100%; height:120px; }


 <div class="divrow">
    <div class="littlebox">first</div>
    <div class="littlebox">second</div>
    <div class="littlebox">third</div>
 </div>

 <div class="divrow">
     <div class="littlebox">first</div><div class="littlebox">second</div><div class="littlebox">third</div>
 </div>
```

These two render differently, in the first row there is a small space between each div, and in the second there are none. Setting the margin to 0px will still make the space visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/F3f3C/

I know that float:left instead of display:inline-block does solve the problem, but I wonder if there is a way to do it without using float.

Comment: `</div class="divrow">` i hope that is a typo..

Comment: The second row has space between them because there is a `margin` of `2px` according to Chrome's inspect element.

Comment: Do you need the whole thing to be like the first row?

Comment: I want the first row to be the same as the second, but dont want to change the html, because it becomes unreadable.

Comment: I fixed your typo and get the same result. How on earth is this dependant on witespace??? Very weird!

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without altering the HTML you have two options:

1. Set the parent's font-size to zero and reset the font-size on the inline-blocked children.
2. Position the elements absolutely (may that be through floating or position: absolute)

Comment: thanks, the first solution works here is the jsfiddle with the changes for anyone interested in the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/2DFaq/1/

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you are using inline-block. Of cause the margin adds som space, but inline-block always makes a bit of space. You can float your div's instead

Comment: setting margin to 0 still adds space, and i did mention I wonder if there is a way to do it without floating the divs

Comment: Well as I state, you get space, when using inline-block.

Comment: if you set font-size to 0, you will get rid of the space bewteen the divs. Then you can have another div inside each, that adds the font-size again